# "SocketException: Unconnected sockets not implemented" with self-signed SSL certificate

Tags: java, ssl

(I've asked the same question of the jmeter-user mailing list, but I wanted to try here as well - so at the least I can update this with the answer once I find it).

I'm having trouble using [JMeter](http://jakarta.apache.org/jmeter/) to test a Tomcat webapp using a self-signed SSL cert. JMeter throws a SocketException with message `Unconnected sockets not implemented`. [According to JMeter's docs](http://jakarta.apache.org/jmeter/usermanual/get-started.html#opt_ssl), the application is designed and written to accept any certificate, self-signed or CA signed or whatever.

Has anyone run into this specific exception before?

I've attempted to export this certificate from the server and import it into my local keystore (with *keytool -import -alias tomcat -file* ), but the result is the same.

I've also tried setting javax.net.debug=all as a JVM arg ([the JSSE reference guide](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/guide/security/jsse/ReadDebug.html) lists this as a debugging step); however, I don't see any debugging output anywhere - should I expect this somewhere other than standard out/error?

Answer (score 14):

Most `javax.net.SocketFactory` implementations define all `createSocket()` methods **that have parameters** as abstract. But have a `createSocket()` method without parameters that looks like this:

```
public Socket createSocket() throws IOException {
   throw new SocketException("Unconnected sockets not implemented");
}
```

So if you subclass the abstract `javax.net.SocketFactory` you will be force to override the methods with parameter, but it's easy to miss to override the `createSocket()` method without parameters. Thus the exception is thrown if your code calls `createSocket()`. Simply override the method and the be done. :)

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem in my code (not related to JMeter).

My code uses a self-defined `SocketFactory`. What I found out is that the class `com.sun.jndi.ldap.Connection` calls some methods of the `SocketFactory` using `Method.invoke()`. One of the methods it tries to call is `createSocket()` - without parameters.

When I added such method to my factory all worked fine.

Answer (score 2):

This is a hint rather than a proper answer: A cursory glance at Google results seems to suggest that the exception is usually caused by the code forcing the use of a default SSL socket factory that on purpose throws the exception when createSocket() is invoked on it. What some of the results seem to suggest is that the issue sometimes happens due to a bug in certain version in Java 6, or when the incorrect path or password is provided to the keystore.

So, I'd say, try using Java 5. Also, try pointing JMeter to a well-known site that uses proper SSL certificates. This way you could test the self-signed certificate hypothesis.

Comment: Can you post some of the links, especially the ones about bugs in certain versions of Java 6?

Comment: 1.6-related:
http://www.nabble.com/CXF-and-Java-6-Update-10-td19463818.html 
https://www.willuhn.de/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=628 
https://bugzilla.kapott.org/show_bug.cgi?id=72
the rest: try Googling :)

Answer (score 0):

I had Web Service problems similar to this with jdk 1.6.0_10.

I upgraded to 1.6.0_16 and everything worked.

Answer (score 0):

Try searching your classpath (in Eclipse, I do ctrl-shift-t to do this) for SSLSocketFactory*. If you find one, set it as a property on the Security class:

In my environment, I've found the following two:

```
Security.setProperty("ssl.SocketFactory.provider", "com.ibm.jsse2.SSLSocketFactoryImpl");
```

or

```
Security.setProperty("ssl.SocketFactory.provider", "com.ibm.websphere.ssl.protocol.SSLSocketFactory");
```

(or for whatever other class you find)

Similarly for `ServerSocketFactory`, if you need server sockets.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution (java 1.6) removing TLS_DHE_ ciphers completely,  force to override the methods createSocket()

(https://gist.github.com/hoangthienan/735afb17ffd6955de95a49aa0138dbaa)