# java.net.SocketException: Unconnected sockets not implemented

Tags: java, sockets, sharepoint, ssl, sharepoint-2010

Trying to connect to sharepoint server using java code and got below stacktrace.I am editing already existing code and changed the url of sharepoint code..I am very new to this sharepoint module..PLease help :)

```
         [java] Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Unconnected is not implemented 
         [java] at javax.net.SocketFactory.createSocket(SocketFactory.java:97)
         [java] at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor3.invoke(Unknown Source)
         [java] at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMet
         hodAccessorImpl.java:25)
         [java] at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:585)
         [java] at org.apache.commons.httpclient.protocol.ReflectionSocketFactor
         y.createSocket(ReflectionSocketFactory.java:116)
         [java] at org.apache.commons.httpclient.protocol.SSLProtocolSocketFacto
         ry.createSocket(SSLProtocolSocketFactory.java:130)
         [java] at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpConnection.open(HttpConnect
         ion.java:707)
         [java] at org.apache.commons.httpclient.MultiThreadedHttpConnectionMana
         ger$HttpConnectionAdapter.open(MultiThreadedHttpConnectionManager.java:1361)
         [java] at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector.executeWithR
         etry(HttpMethodDirector.java:387)
        [java] at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector.executeMetho
        d(HttpMethodDirector.java:171)
         [java] at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient.executeMethod(HttpCl
         ient.java:397)
           [java] at org.apache.axis.transport.http.CommonsHTTPSender.invoke(Commo
         nsHTTPSender.java:196)
```

Code:

```
public boolean windowsNTLMAuthentication(String uname, String pass, String server, String urlAddress, String domain) { 
    try { 
        NtlmAuthenticator authenticator = new NtlmAuthenticator();     
        authenticator.setAuthentication(userName, password);  
        NtlmJcifsCredentials.register(userName, password, server, domain); 
        stub = new ListsLocator(); 
        EngineConfiguration econfig = stub.getEngineConfiguration();  
        stub.setListsSoapEndpointAddress(urlAddress);  
        stub.setEngineConfiguration(econfig); 
        stub.setMaintainSession(true); 
    } catch (Exception ex) { 
        ex.printStackTrace(); 
        return false; 
    }
}
```

Comment: public boolean windowsNTLMAuthentication(String uname, String pass,
String server, String urlAddress, String domain) {

try {

NtlmAuthenticator authenticator = new NtlmAuthenticator();
authenticator.setAuthentication(userName, password);
NtlmJcifsCredentials.register(userName, password, server, domain);
stub = new ListsLocator();
EngineConfiguration econfig = stub.getEngineConfiguration();
stub.setListsSoapEndpointAddress(urlAddress);
stub.setEngineConfiguration(econfig);
stub.setMaintainSession(true);
} catch (Exception ex) {
ex.printStackTrace();
return false;
}
Sent at 4:29 PM on Tuesday

Comment: Hi andremoniy.. I think they are using the above method to authenticate.. I am not much aware.. I am calling this method in my class..  Thanks for the interest

Comment: Maybe this can help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1739063/httpclient-java-net-socketexception-unconnected-sockets-not-implemented-thrown

Comment: @somorita You should have edited that code into your question. You can see for yourself it's illegible as a comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The socket exception is in turn due to SSL handshake which is not happening between the servers which means that there is no valid ccertificate.

First you need to generate certificate using the following code

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.URL;

import java.security.*;
import java.security.cert.*;

import javax.net.ssl.*;

public class InstallCert {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        String host;
        int port;
        char[] passphrase;
        if ((args.length == 1) || (args.length == 2)) {
            String[] c = args[0].split(":");
            host = c[0];
            port = (c.length == 1) ? 443 : Integer.parseInt(c[1]);
            String p = (args.length == 1) ? "changeit" : args[1];
            passphrase = p.toCharArray();
        } else {
            System.out.println("Usage: java InstallCert <host>[:port] [passphrase]");
            return;
        }

        File file = new File("jssecacerts");
        if (file.isFile() == false) {
            char SEP = File.separatorChar;
            File dir = new File(System.getProperty("java.home") + SEP
                    + "lib" + SEP + "security");
            file = new File(dir, "jssecacerts");
            if (file.isFile() == false) {
                file = new File(dir, "cacerts");
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Loading KeyStore " + file + "...");
        InputStream in = new FileInputStream(file);
        KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.getDefaultType());
        ks.load(in, passphrase);
        in.close();

        SSLContext context = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
        TrustManagerFactory tmf =
            TrustManagerFactory.getInstance(TrustManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
        tmf.init(ks);
        X509TrustManager defaultTrustManager = (X509TrustManager)tmf.getTrustManagers()[0];
        SavingTrustManager tm = new SavingTrustManager(defaultTrustManager);
        context.init(null, new TrustManager[] {tm}, null);
        SSLSocketFactory factory = context.getSocketFactory();

        System.out.println("Opening connection to " + host + ":" + port + "...");
        SSLSocket socket = (SSLSocket)factory.createSocket(host, port);
        socket.setSoTimeout(10000);
        try {
            System.out.println("Starting SSL handshake...");
            socket.startHandshake();
            socket.close();
            System.out.println();
            System.out.println("No errors, certificate is already trusted");
        } catch (SSLException e) {
            System.out.println();
            e.printStackTrace(System.out);
        }

        X509Certificate[] chain = tm.chain;
        if (chain == null) {
            System.out.println("Could not obtain server certificate chain");
            return;
        }

        BufferedReader reader =
                new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("Server sent " + chain.length + " certificate(s):");
        System.out.println();
        MessageDigest sha1 = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA1");
        MessageDigest md5 = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");
        for (int i = 0; i < chain.length; i++) {
            X509Certificate cert = chain[i];
            System.out.println
                (" " + (i + 1) + " Subject " + cert.getSubjectDN());
            System.out.println("   Issuer  " + cert.getIssuerDN());
            sha1.update(cert.getEncoded());
            System.out.println("   sha1    " + toHexString(sha1.digest()));
            md5.update(cert.getEncoded());
            System.out.println("   md5     " + toHexString(md5.digest()));
            System.out.println();
        }

        System.out.println("Enter certificate to add to trusted keystore or 'q' to quit: [1]");
        String line = reader.readLine().trim();
        int k;
        try {
            k = (line.length() == 0) ? 0 : Integer.parseInt(line) - 1;
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            System.out.println("KeyStore not changed");
            return;
        }

        X509Certificate cert = chain[k];
        String alias = host + "-" + (k + 1);
        ks.setCertificateEntry(alias, cert);

        OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("jssecacerts");
        ks.store(out, passphrase);
        out.close();

        System.out.println();
        System.out.println(cert);
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println
                ("Added certificate to keystore 'jssecacerts' using alias '"
                + alias + "'");
    }

    private static final char[] HEXDIGITS = "0123456789abcdef".toCharArray();

    private static String toHexString(byte[] bytes) {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(bytes.length * 3);
        for (int b : bytes) {
            b &= 0xff;
            sb.append(HEXDIGITS[b >> 4]);
            sb.append(HEXDIGITS[b & 15]);
            sb.append(' ');
        }
        return sb.toString();
    }

    private static class SavingTrustManager implements X509TrustManager {

        private final X509TrustManager tm;
        private X509Certificate[] chain;

        SavingTrustManager(X509TrustManager tm) {
            this.tm = tm;
        }

        public X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
            throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
        }

        public void checkClientTrusted(X509Certificate[] chain, String authType)
                throws CertificateException {
            throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
        }

        public void checkServerTrusted(X509Certificate[] chain, String authType)
                throws CertificateException {
            this.chain = chain;
            tm.checkServerTrusted(chain, authType);
        }
    }

}
```

Once the cert file is generated, import the same before authenticating as shown below(Ex:):

System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore", "path of the generated cert file");
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword", "changeit");
boolean auth = windowsNTLMAuthentication(username, pwd, host, url, domain);

This resolves the SSl handshake as well as socket exception